# Staff Web Service Framework

Tags: c++, web-services, frameworks, staff-wsf

How does Staff web service framework compare to others for c++?

Comment: Hi, did my reply help you or didn't you see it yet? Regards, Chris

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the response, it was perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot answer your question in all details, but I'm searching for C++ SOA / web service frameworks for a year now.

My favorites (all OpenSource and platform independent - not ordered) are currently:

**GSOAP** - http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

pros:

- proven, reliable, very fast
- big documentation, many support
- still maintained - releases every 3-6 months

contras:

- WSDL/client generators are not free
- programming and embedding into existing apps isn't so easy
- seems to be more C than C++

**Apache AXIS/C++** - http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/index.html

pros:

- proven, already in use in big projects
- (nearly) good documentation
- up to date, maintenance is ensured by Apache Foundation
- better/nicer C++ API

contras:

- heavy weight SDK / too many functionality for me
- not easy to implement it / many work to embed it into own app
- maybe not as fast and bigger footprint as GSOAP

**Staff** - http://code.google.com/p/staff/

pros:

- very small footprint
- easy and fast to integrate

contras:

- future maintenance is not clear / it's (only) a Google summer of code project
- very early stage
- support party only in cyrillic

If I have to decide for a framework right now, I would take **Apache AXIS** -
it's proven and reliable and thus ready for productive use.
Further it's future maintenance is guaranteed by the Apache Foundation
and I'm free to uase, modify and integrate AXIS as I want - even for my
commercial applications.

I hope that helped a little bit.

Comment: Is this possible for you to update the answer?

Comment: Sorry, but I skipped working on the starving SOAP protocol. I instead switched to much more up-to-date and leightweight Ajax/JSON. See jQuery or Dojo Toolkit.